# Difference between meaning of Elohim and Elohe

Tags: hebrew

What is the difference in meaning between Elohim and Elohe?

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, you should maybe include the Hebrew spelling of these words. I _think_ I know what you mean by "elohe", but...

Comment: Do you mean the difference between אלהים (Elohim) and אלוה (Eloha)? Or for the latter do you mean אלהי (Elohei)?

Answer (score 2):

The former is "God", the latter is "God of", such as "God of Abraham" (Elohe Avraham)

The latter is from the grammatical construct called סמיכות which is a way of connecting noun-noun pairs. In english, we use "of", but in hebrew there are quite a few ways of doing this. של is usually used in place of "of" in hebrew, but in this case, we modify the first word, with the suffix "ey" (which is what we do for plural words, which God's name is in Torah), so it becomes Elohei Avraham.

Comment: assuming the intent is "elo-hei" and not just "elohe"

Comment: Good answer. Maybe add a little more explanation of the idea of סמיכות in Hebrew, and a couple more examples?

Comment: @rosends what is "just elohe"

Comment: I don't know. That's why I assumed that Rabbi Kalli, in his answer read it as elo-hei.

Comment: In Betset Yisrael, don't we say "Eloah Yaakov"?  Alternate spelling?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Rav Yoel Bin-Nun explains that Elo-ah is the singular for Elo-him, and is a way of saying's God's name without any other connotations. The other word, El, means power, and can be used in many contexts, referring to judges, idols, and even great men.